# react image source does not working from the folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently using codesandbox unfortunately still the image does not display icon in the react app

[image: Edit nostalgic-http-p66is]

**Is it necessary to declare at the beginning all the images ?**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import iconSet from "./image_source";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  console.log(iconSet);
  const availables = ["man", "sun"];

  const renderList = () => {
    return iconSet.map(item => {
      const result = availables.findIndex(
        available => available === item.string
      );

      if (result > -1) {
        return (
          <li key={item.string}>
            {item.badge}
            <img alt={item.string} src={`./${item.badge}.svg`} />
          </li>
        );
      }
      return null;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Here is the available icons</h1>
      <ul>{renderList()}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Will this work ? `src={require(\`./${item.badge}.svg\`)}`

Comment: @Pavindu not really, `require` also tried

Comment: was your problem solved? I'm eager to know the solution if you've been managed to solve that..

Comment: @Pavindu not yet

Answer (score 0):

Moving the assets to the public folder and making this change solves the issue

```
<img alt={item.string} src={window.location.origin + `./${item.badge}.svg`} />
```